# PC doesn't turn on on first try on the power button

Tags: power

Every morning when I try to turn on my computer, it doesn't boot. 
It will only boot after several tries on pushing the power button. The PSU is alright as it powers the other fans immediately.

When it turns on, no other problems happen. Everything is fine, only the startup is the problem.

Specs:
H61M-VS Asrock Mobo
Intel G620 2.60 GHz
4gb RAM
NVIDIA GT610 1GB
ATX-550-W PSU

UPDATE: After the new case, I can turn it on with no problems. The problem is in the front panel wires or the power button. Thanks everyone!

Comment: is it possible that the power button is a soft on button, and not an instant on, hardware key?

Comment: Please explain the exact behavior: Does your PC perhaps turn on, then immediately off again, then on again, by itself? Or do you have to actually press the power button multiple times? If that is the case, what happens when you press it and it doesn’t work? Also, please update your question with each and every piece of hardware built into your PC, *with exact make and model*.

Comment: Edited my question.
I actually need to press the power button multiple times until it opens successfully.

Comment: It the date/time in the BIOS is wrong when it is not switching on then it needs a new CMOS battery, especially if the motherboard is more than three or four years old. Or is there any reason to suspect the power button may be a bit worn out?

Comment: If I buy a new case would the front panel wires be changed? Because I also suspect that the problem is in the power button itself.

Comment: @Zeratul1339: Your PC is clearly reacting to your button press. That means it’s working. It’s not the button.

Comment: @DanielB: I disagree. I've seen this exact same symptom on an old cabinet and turned out the power button was worn out (as Andrew Morton surmised) and would make proper contact only intermittently after many presses. Eventually it stopped working altogether. I'd look into replacing the button first of all (if possible with the cabinet) and then perhaps the PSU.

Comment: I'm going to buy a new case today and probably a PSU. I will update you guys later.

Comment: more probably is the new PSU that solved your problem, the power button is used only to electrically power on the PC, his work is just a initial click and after the board take ownership of power :) ( the old button did that)

Comment: I didn't buy a new PSU because it worked perfectly with the new case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers here.

Really the only solution is that the PSU isn't alright since it can't turn on the computer.  A PSU has multiple connectors and while some of them may be okay, the one supplying power to the motherboard isn't.  A new PSU is the only thing to do.

The second, albeit less likely solution is that the motherboard is failing. Since you don't say the computer cuts out by itself, I find this unlikely as a faulty motherboard connector will fail intermittently.

Comment: It never shuts down by itself. After a successful startup, everything goes smoothly.

Comment: It's the PSU.  Change that and it will all work fine.

Comment: Ok I'll check. But could the problem be on the front panel wires? Because the fans go on and the GPU heats up a bit even if the CPU is still off.